# How to convert extract webpage data variable into string using python script or java script in power desktop automate?

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to convert the output of extract webpages data to a string but getting an error.

Using python script action I tried (here htmlString is an output variable from the "Extract Data from webpage" action).

tom = str("'htmlString'")

return tom

and

tom = str("%htmlString%")

return tom even without quotation, read somewhere that three quotations worked but it did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated I m stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer, it worked when I used triple quotes:

```
str("""%htmlstring%""")
```